# Android Eclipse - Database Login Issue

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, authentication

Good afternoon,

I am trying to create a simple user profile and allow user's to log in once they have created their account to login with their saved username and password.

The account details arent successfully saving and I am getting the error message which I have set that username and password do not match?

I cannot see the error in my code and have ben unable to solve my issue. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Database Helper:

```
package com.new.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name,CursorFactory factory, int version) 
    {
               super(context, name, factory, version);
    }
    // Called when no database exists in disk and the helper class needs
    // to create a new one.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) 
    {
            _db.execSQL(LoginDataBaseAdapter.DATABASE_CREATE);

    }
    // Called when there is a database version mismatch meaning that the version
    // of the database on disk needs to be upgraded to the current version.
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion) 
    {
            // Log the version upgrade.
            Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +_oldVersion + " to " +_newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");


            // Upgrade the existing database to conform to the new version. Multiple
            // previous versions can be handled by comparing _oldVersion and _newVersion
            // values.
            // The simplest case is to drop the old table and create a new one.
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TEMPLATE");
            // Create a new one.
            onCreate(_db);
    }


}
```

SignUPActivity:

```
package com.techblogon.loginexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SignUPActivity extends Activity
{
    EditText editTextUserName,editTextPassword,editTextConfirmPassword, editTextCurrentWeight, editTextTargetWeight, editTextBMI;
    Button btnCreateAccount;

    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);

        // get Instance  of Database Adapter
        loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

        // Get Refferences of Views
        editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextConfirmPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);
        editTextCurrentWeight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextCurrentWeight);
        editTextTargetWeight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextTargetWeight);
        editTextBMI=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextBMI);

        btnCreateAccount=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);
        btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
            String confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
            String currentweight=editTextCurrentWeight.getText().toString();
            String targetweight=editTextTargetWeight.getText().toString();
            String bmi=editTextBMI.getText().toString();

            // check if any of the fields are vacant
            if(userName.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals("")||currentweight.equals("")||targetweight.equals("")||bmi.equals(""))
            {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
            }
            // check if both password matches
            if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                // Save the Data in Database
                loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(userName, password, currentweight, targetweight, bmi);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }
}
```

LoginDatabaseAdapter:

```
package com.techblogon.loginexample;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class LoginDataBaseAdapter 
{
        static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
        static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
        // TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
        // SQL Statement to create a new database.
        static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"STUDENT"+
                                     "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text); ";
        // Variable to hold the database instance
        public  SQLiteDatabase db;
        // Context of the application using the database.
        private final Context context;
        // Database open/upgrade helper
        private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
        public  LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
        {
            context = _context;
            dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        public  LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
        {
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }
        public void close() 
        {
            db.close();
        }

        public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
        {
            return db;
        }

        public void insertEntry(String userName,String password, String currentweight, String targetweight, String bmi)
        {
           ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
            // Assign values for each row.
            newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
            newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);
            newValues.put("CURRENTWEIGHT",currentweight);
            newValues.put("TARGETWEIGHT",targetweight);
            newValues.put("BMI",bmi);


            // Insert the row into your table
            db.insert("STUDENT", null, newValues);
            ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        public int deleteEntry(String UserName)
        {
            //String id=String.valueOf(ID);
            String where="USERNAME=?";
            int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete("STUDENT", where, new String[]{UserName}) ;
           // Toast.makeText(context, "Number of Entry Deleted Successfully : "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
        }   
        public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName)
        {
            Cursor cursor=db.query("STUDENT", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
            {
                cursor.close();
                return "NOT EXIST";
            }
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
            cursor.close();
            return password;                
        }
        public void  updateEntry(String userName,String password, String currentweight, String targetweight, String bmi)
        {
            // Define the updated row content.
            ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
            // Assign values for each row.
            updatedValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
            updatedValues.put("PASSWORD",password);
            updatedValues.put("CURRENTWEIGHT",currentweight);
            updatedValues.put("TARGETWEIGHT",targetweight);
            updatedValues.put("BMI",bmi);

            String where="USERNAME = ?";
            db.update("STUDENT",updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});             
        }       
}
```

HomeActivity:

```
package com.techblogon.loginexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity 
{
    Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

         // create a instance of SQLite Database
         loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
         loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

         // Get The Reference Of Buttons
         btnSignIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIN);
         btnSignUp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUP);

        // Set OnClick Listener on SignUp button 
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            /// Create Intent for SignUpActivity  and Start The Activity
            Intent intentSignUP=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUPActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentSignUP);
            }
        });
    }
    // Methos to handleClick Event of Sign In Button
    public void signIn(View V)
       {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HomeActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
            dialog.setTitle("STUDENT");

            // get the Refferences of views
            final  EditText editTextUserName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
            final  EditText editTextPassword=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);

            Button btnSignIn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);

            // Set On ClickListener
            btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // get The User name and Password
                    String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                    String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                    // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
                    String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);

                    // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
                    if(password.equals(storedPassword))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Login Successful, Welcome to UCC Pocket Coach, Get Fit Fast!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        Intent ii=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,MainMenu.class);
                        startActivity(ii);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Close The Database
        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }
}
```

I appear to be getting this error in the log files and am unsure how to alter my code to ensure it saves correctly

Error:

```
02-25 15:55:21.798: E/SQLiteLog(24494): (1) table STUDENT has no column named TARGETWEIGHT
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494): Error inserting TARGETWEIGHT=79 USERNAME=111496858 PASSWORD=hurling1 CURRENTWEIGHT=75 BMI=22.4
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table STUDENT has no column named TARGETWEIGHT (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO STUDENT(TARGETWEIGHT,USERNAME,PASSWORD,CURRENTWEIGHT,BMI) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at com.techblogon.loginexample.LoginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(LoginDataBaseAdapter.java:56)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at com.techblogon.loginexample.SignUPActivity$1.onClick(SignUPActivity.java:62)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-25 15:55:21.812: E/SQLiteDatabase(24494):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

ALL HELP GREATLY APPRECIATED!

Comment: Sorry, you just edited so I will have to change my answer...

Comment: I edited my answer, check it out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error can be this line:

```
static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"STUDENT"+
                                 "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text); ";
```

you do not have "CurrentWeight" and "TargetWeight" properties in your database.
You should change to something like this:

```
static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"STUDENT"+
                                 "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text,CURRENTWEIGHT real,TARGETWEIGHT real,BMI real); ";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much simple mistake but great to have helpful people like you to help, many thanks!!

Comment: @apoorva Thanks so much, simple error from my behalf but thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

When you create the table (the Create statement), you don't include TARGETWEIGHT, CURRENTHEIGHT or BMI. Include those three columns in the statement and you should be fine.

That's what the error message says too. It can't find the TARGETWEIGHT column because it doesn't exist. :)